# set default tab active when page loads Angular 8

Tags: angular

After successful login, it redirects to lochalhost:4200/feature. I want to make the 'dashboard' link active in this state. When i click on dashboard, test suit and logs links active works fine.

```
<li routerLink="dashboard"  [ngClass]="{'active': router.isActive('feature')}" routerLinkActive="active">
            <i class="img-sprite dashboard-icon"></i>
           <a  > Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li routerLink="test-suit" routerLinkActive="active" >
                <i class="img-sprite testsuit-icon"></i>
            <a>Test Suite</a>
        </li>
        <li routerLink="logs" routerLinkActive="active">
                <i class="img-sprite logs-icon"></i>
                <a>Logs</a></li>
```

Problem is after adding ngClass, active class is not removing from 'dashboard' link.

These are the urls:

```
http://localhost:4200/feature     (default page url where i want to give active class as this url loads dashboard component)
http://localhost:4200/feature/dashboard    (active works fine)
http://localhost:4200/feature/test-suite   (active works fine)
http://localhost:4200/feature/logs   (active works fine)
```

Answer (score 1):

Due same route active is not working.

here is soln:

```
 <li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" >
</li>
```

Here is the reference:
https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

Comment: Basically i want to give active class to  <li routerLink="dashboard"> on '/feature' url. This url loads the dashboard component.

Comment: u can try like this ... and no need to add ngclass just simple write active css class <li routerLink="dashboard" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" >
</li>